# How to place css of ampcssframework to become valid AMP Page?

Tags: html, css, validation, amp-html

I'm using [ampcssframework](https://www.ampcssframework.com/) however when i do amp test, it return error:

> The author stylesheet specified in tag 'style amp-custom' is too long - document contains 116909 bytes whereas the limit is 75000 bytes.

[image]

note: i place the `css` code under `<head>` at same file of index.html

```
<style amp-custom>

      /*!
      * AMP CSS Framework v4.4.1 (https://www.ampcssframework.com/)
      * Based/build on Bootstrap (https://getbootstrap.com/)
      * Copyright 2018-2020 AMP CSS Framework
      */
        :root{--blue: ##0084b4;--indigo: #6610f2;--purple: #6f42c1;--pink: #e83e8c;--red:

      ....

<style amp-custom>
```

any idea to place the `css` of `ampcssframework`  so my page will be valid?

Comment: lay out your head tag, we need to see how you insert styles. Now I specially downloaded amp-source.min.css and shows that it weighs 40kb.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov please see update question

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov that's right it just only 40kb, but if you put the code under `<style amp-custom>` it will return this error

Comment: Thank you for answering. I'll try to check it out today.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, your link to ampcssframework doesn't open anymore. Please send all the CSS code of this framework, for example, to Gist.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov Hi, now the web can be opened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're putting styles on the page incorrectly. I have no errors. It's possible that you just have a syntax error in your code. Or you inserted the styles twice .

**Here's a look at the steps:**

**1).** After downloading the archive. In the CSS folder I saw the following files:

[image: screenshot]

I don't know why there are so many files in there or what kind of files you need. I'll take this one as an example: *amp-source.min.css*

**2).** I insert all styles from amp-source.min.css into the AMP page:

```html
<!--
     This is the minimum valid AMP HTML document. Type away
     here and the AMP Validator will re-check your document on the fly.
-->
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="canonical" href="self.html">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1">
  <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  
  <style amp-custom>
  /*!
 * AMP CSS Framework v4.4.1 (https://www.ampcssframework.com/)
 * Based/build on Bootstrap (https://getbootstrap.com/)
 * Copyright 2018-2020 AMP CSS Framework
 */:root{--blue: #0084b4;--indigo: #6610f2;}
  </style>
  
  </head>
<body>Hello, AMP world.</body>
</html>
```

There are no errors in the AMP validator, check it yourself: https://validator.ampproject.org/

See the full version on Codepen: https://codepen.io/alexandr-kazakov/pen/QWNKLLg

**Note.** In any case, I do not recommend you to use this CSS framework, it weighs too much for AMP. 40-50KB just for the framework, it is too much.

Comment: Hi @Alex Thank you for the answer, I will look for it.

Answer (score 2):

The error is referring to the size of your css. You must shorten your css size within the amp limit (75,000):

-use only the styles in that specific page.
-use relative path for images, etc.
-use shorthand properties
-use a css optimizer (https://css.github.io/csso/csso.html)
Melo

Comment: the css has been minimized by default